# How to check if the file open? using std::filesystem

Tags: c++, c++17, filesystems

I have a cycle:

```
// const std::string & current_path_

for(const auto & i : std::filesystem::directory_iterator(current_path_))
{
    if (std::filesystem::is_directory(i))
     {
         code;
     }
     else // i  is a file
     {
         if (i.is_open()) code; // it doesn`t work/ there is no is_open() method
     }
}
```

how to check if a file is open?? if the file is open? i will not do anything

Comment: How do you plan on detecting a file on a network file system being opened on another system?

Comment: `std::filesystem::directory_entry` doesn't open anything. It just represents a file in a filesystem. Are you trying to create a file stream based on the path pointed to by `i`?

Comment: Hard to do in a general sense. Nothing globally requires that a file advertise that it is open. Remember that C++ has to support a very large umbrella of target platforms

Comment: What does "if a file is open" mean, exactly?

Comment: i make a program which will encrypt files. the user enters the file type and the path to search for all the matching files. the program goes through all folders and files of this path. and encrypts the appropriate files. if a file is open, you can't touch it and change it. I want to do protection in the program,It is the task. this is why i must to check: is a current file open or not now in a PC?

Comment: i dont want to  open a file, i  need to check. It is a protection